# Greasemonkey to prompt outlook

Tags: outlook, greasemonkey

I have a new Script I'm building for my office where a greasemonkey button, aside from prompting to enter an specific error number also needs to open outlook and send a message to a certain address with said error number in the subject line...

Any ideas I'm tapped out

Code:

```
addButton(f_l, 'Error number', function() {
url = prompt("Please provide the full error number","");
surround('<a href="mailto: bob@test.com?&subject=Error ' + url + ' Raised&amp;"></a>','');
});
```

It enters the text into the box on the page, but it doesn't create a new email.

Comment: What if you created a mailto <a> link, and used JS to artificially click on it and open outlook?

Comment: Will give this a try and see how far I get, they arnt giving me much time to complete this project at the moment but ill update when I find something solid, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article describes all the required steps for automating Outlook from another applications.

Also see [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/).